# Call a function from another stateful class in the build method of a class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two stateful classes and I want to trigger the function `triggerFunction()` from one class in second class's build method with onPressed event of a button. Here are the both classes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TriggerClass extends StatefulWidget {
  const TriggerClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TriggerClass> createState() => _TriggerClassState();
}

class _TriggerClassState extends State<TriggerClass> {

  void triggerFunction(){}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

The Second class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UIClass extends StatefulWidget {
  const UIClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UIClass> createState() => _UIClassState();
}

class _UIClassState extends State<UIClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
             // Here I want to call triggerFunction()
          },
          child: const Text('Trigger Function'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If I use simple class without state, it does call the function but when using stateful, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you remove `_` from `TriggerClassState()`

### Make Class Public

Your **Trigger Class included with Function**

```
class TriggerClass extends StatefulWidget {
  const TriggerClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TriggerClass> createState() => TriggerClassState();
}

class TriggerClassState extends State<TriggerClass> {
  void triggerFunction() {
    print('Button Pressed');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Your **UIClass Widget call your triggerFunction**

```
class UIClass extends StatefulWidget {
  const UIClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UIClass> createState() => _UIClassState();
}

class _UIClassState extends State<UIClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Here I want to call triggerFunction()
            TriggerClassState().triggerFunction();
          },
          child: const Text('Trigger Function'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Other Way Without class public or Using Constructor

**Trigger Class:**

```
class TriggerClass extends StatefulWidget {
  const TriggerClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TriggerClass> createState() => _TriggerClassState();
}

class _TriggerClassState extends State<TriggerClass> {
  void triggerFunction() {
    print('Button Pressed');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: UIClass(
        voidFunction: triggerFunction,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**UI Class**

```
class UIClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function voidFunction;
  const UIClass({required this.voidFunction, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UIClass> createState() => _UIClassState();
}

class _UIClassState extends State<UIClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Here I want to call triggerFunction()
            widget.voidFunction();
          },
          child: const Text('Trigger Function'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it says, The method 'triggerFunction' isn't defined for the type 'TriggerClass'

Comment: its working on my side, have you try my code?

Comment: It worked. I was using TriggerClass instead of TriggerClassState. is there any way without making the class public?

Comment: Helpful. However, my scenario is bit complex. I have a lot going on UI screen with some required parameters as well. TriggerClass is accessed on UI class with some parameters and there is lot going on the TriggerClass as well. I was wondering if there's a way I can only send a trigger for this function.

Comment: @Tahir If you want only `triggerFunction()` on button pressed yes this is also possible just declare yout `triggerFunction()` ouside the class and used it on buttonPressed, if you dont understand please let me know

Comment: Yes, please. Here's the workflow. It's sort of media player. `UIClass` that has controls and calls the `TriggerClass` to run media. `triggerFunction` takes values from a timer function and the widget(from UIClass, and TriggerClass itself) and hits an API.  If I move function outside the class I can't get the values of controllers and timers of the mediaplayer.

Comment: @Tahir If you want values of controllers and timers or any value from class/widget then You need to use above any 1 method without Constructor or class has public you don't access any value

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I got the point!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you have a method in a `triggerClass` and you want to call it from the `uiClass`. right?
for that, you have to forward the pointer of that method from `triggerCLass` to UiClass through `Navigator`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TriggerClass extends StatefulWidget {
  const TriggerClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TriggerClass> createState() => _TriggerClassState();
}

class _TriggerClassState extends State<TriggerClass> {

  void triggerFunction(){}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
......//somewhere in these widgets you have onPressed() for navigation. 
      onPressed: (){
      Navigator.push(
      context,
         MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const 
       UIClass(trigger: triggerFunction)), //Here you will pass the method pointer by calling constructor
  );
}

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and in UIClass receive the method from the constructor and call it wherever you want.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UIClass extends StatefulWidget {
final Function trigger;

  const UIClass({Key? key, required this.trigger}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UIClass> createState() => _UIClassState();
}

class _UIClassState extends State<UIClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            widget.trigger();  //call it like this
          },
          child: const Text('Trigger Function'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use Navigator as I need to remain on the same screen and Trigger the function.